# vuejs how to display div based on dynamic array values?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to show/hide a new div if any of the user links clicked:

```
<ul id="pm-tabs"> 
  <li v-for="user in unreadMsgsList">       
     <a @click="openPMbox(user)"> ${user}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

the method is:

```
    openPMbox: function(user) {              
         this.isPmBoxOpenList[user] = !this.isPmBoxOpenList[user];
    },
```

the user data is stored at `isPmBoxOpenList: []` and I can verify that it is properly filled.

The window that should show/hide is like this and is out of `v-for` loop above:

```
<div class="pmbox" v-bind:disabled=="isPmBoxOpenList" >Some Text </div>
```

But I get error at template. Not sure how should I define `pmbox` so appreciate your hints.

**P.S.** It worths mentioning `user` is not define in `data`. It is only an object in `isPmBoxOpenList` array.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: The error that I get is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null
    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (app.js:68)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `v-if`, to display or hide like this:

```
<div class="pmbox" v-if="isPmBoxOpenList[user]" >Some Text </div>
```

Comment: Well, this gives: `ReferenceError: user is not defined`. Not surprising as user is not in global context.

Comment: in `v-if` you have to give the variable based on which you want to show or hide the div

Comment: Right, but the very question is how to bind that `v-if` variable to an array variable which is not itself defined as a data variable.

Comment: @Karlom Well I could not figure out from the question that it isn''t part of data variable. v-if will be able to access one of `data` variable, computed property, method. It will not be aware of other variables.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear in the question. So what you reckon  as appropriate solution in this circumstances?

Comment: @Karlom Can you add more code around `<div class="pmbox"`, Any issue in adding this variable: `isPmBoxOpenList` in data or computed property? What is the exact condition on which you want to hide the div?

Comment: Well, the issue is that there can be unknown number of `users` so the only solution hat I could think of was to store them in an array. Not sure about computed property though, as I'm so noob in vue.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138327/discussion-between-saurabh-and-karlom).